# Wrapping column name of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to wrap the column names of a data frame to some specific width. For instance, transform

```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0                       -1.526078                        0.258110
1                        0.263490                       -0.268635
2                       -1.264121                       -1.257454
```

to something like

```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa      aaaaaaaaaaaaa
0      -1.526078         0.258110
1       0.263490        -0.268635
2      -1.264121        -1.257454
```

There is a solution to this problem in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093281/6246880), but it only works in jupyter notebooks, not in regular python.

Code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=['a' * 30] * 2)
print(df)
```

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092345/wrapping-column-names-in-python-pandas-dataframe-or-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: This is the question I mentioned in my post. The answers provided in this thread work only for jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the `DataFrame` in your own class which would override the [`__str__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095294/override-repr-or-pprint-for-int) and/or [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095294/override-repr-or-pprint-for-int) methods to achieve this.